# How would one add custom made 3rd party pieces to LEGO Digital Designer?

Tags: software, ldd

There are a number of producers of custom LEGO compatible pieces, how would one add such a custom piece to the LDD software, or otherwise make use of them?

Comment: Anybody at all? Not even a mention of what 3d format is being used?

Comment: Do you mean Lego Digital Designer?

Comment: I believe that is the current iteration. I am speaking specifically of the software available from the Lego company.

Comment: I thought I would clarify so I could update the question to hopefully get some more attention.

Comment: Thanks. For the record, I am willing to consider answers that address other software as well. But I currently only have the LDD, so am completely unfamiliar to any other software out there.

Comment: I believe it should be possible in most LEGO CAD applications, but LDD being a LEGO product it's unlikely they would officially support this type of feature. That's not to say it isn't possible.

Comment: Rin Rio-oki's answer is off the point i think hes asking for websites that are hosting more parts that can be manually added the Lego Digital Designer

Comment: @justanboy nijineko stated that they were willing to consider other software - and seeing as Studio offers both support for, and a tool to create custom parts, and is now officially supported by TLG in place of LDD, it's on point.

Comment: @justanboy thank you for your suggestion. I have attempted to improve my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the comments you wrote:

> ...For the record, I am willing to consider answers that address
>   other software as well. But I currently only have the LDD, so am
>   completely unfamiliar to any other software out there. – nijineko

*Brinklink* offers two programs that could be right up your alley:

1. [*Studio 2.0*](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/download.page) - A popular alternative to *LEGO Digital
   Designer*, and
   [image]
2. [*PartDesigner*](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/partdesigner.page) - A side-tweak program to make custom bricks,
   where    you're able to export directly into the *Studio 2.0* program.
   [image]